# Unable to modify LD_CONFIG_PATH from script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, environment-variables

I'm trying to write a script that adds some path to LD_CONFIG_PATH in order to not get "`blabla.so` not found". The problem is that my script is able to modify its own context (via export) but it doesn't affect other shells. I want to set the a variable globally so it persists between reboots and shells.

My current script looks like:

```
LDPATH='/opt/mqm/lib64'
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LDPATH:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
ldconfig
```

which I run like

```
sudo ./set_my_ld_path.sh
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And it returns nothing (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is empty).

I also tried

```
LDPATH='/opt/mqm/lib64' env
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LDPATH:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
ldconfig
```

but it only writes all my existing variables such as PATH/LANG/HOME/LC_TIME/...

For example, I can run following script in powershell and it does what I'd like to have here:

```
# setting an environment variable for current and descendant processes, same as bash `export`
$env:OPENCV_DIR = $OPENCV_DIR

# applying it machine-wide, persists between users/shells/reboots
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("OPENCV_DIR", $env:OPENCV_DIR, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

How could it be done?

Comment: Try loging in as `root` with `sudo -i`, then execute your script normally and echo the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` afterwards. My guess is that your changes are done for the `root` user that is executing the command and that they are lost when `sudo` ends.

Comment: @Iskustvo no, this behavior persists for `root` user too, I run the command without sudo (as I'm already logged as root) and it gets executed successfully, but I don't see the variable change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, assignments can not have spaces around the `=`.

Secondly, you can never affect the current environment from a child process (a script).

To run a script that sets an environment variable, and have that change affect the current environment, you will need to source the script using either `.` (dot), or `source` in `bash`.

You may also not source a script through `sudo` (it's unclear why you are using `sudo` at all in this case).

This means that you can have a script file like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/mqm/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

which you then source using either

```
. ./file
```

or

```
source ./file
```

Setting (and exporting) the variable in your shell startup file for interactive shells (`~/.bashrc` if you use `bash`), would set it "globally" (for all processes started from the shell).

Comment: Sorry for spaces around `=`, it just a habit to place them automatically, I don't actually have them in my script. `source` seems to be an option, but it has to be mixed somehow with `sudo` because of different commands in the script (such as ldconfig) that requires it. And even if I remove all sudos and modify `LD_CONFIG_PATH` in my parent process it doesn't modifies other consoles.

Comment: Please, see edit.

Comment: Well, I ended up with adding `source` as well as modifying `/etc/profile` for next runs.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy See added bit. You may also set it in `~/.bash_profile`.  Setting it in `/etc/profile` would affect other users.

Comment: I actually have found out it's more convinient to do `echo '/opt/mqm/lib64' > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mqm.conf && ldconfig`. Works like a charm.